# Ember Actions 2: Using Variables Action Names

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dynamic-programming

I am trying to figure out how to pass a list of actions to the template and iterate over each of these actions using the each handlebar.

What I would like to do is something like this where the list variable is defined in the controller like so:

```
   App.CoolController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    currentActions:['action1','action2'],
    actions:{
        action1: function(){
            alert('bar');
        },
        action2: function(){
            alert('baz');
        }
    });
```

And the template can iterate over them like this:

```
{{#each currentAction in currentActions}}
    <div {{action currentAction model}}>currentAction</div>
{{/each}}
```

Has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally, I just did it with your code ;)  Except you are missing a bracket closing your actions hash.

```
App.IndexController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
        currentActions:['action1','action2'],
        actions:{
            action1: function(model){
                alert('bar ' + model);
            },
            action2: function(model){
                alert('baz ' + model);
            }
        }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jutuba/1/edit

Comment: I understood the question to mean both actions would fire on each item, you have two items with two separate actions.

Comment: oh, maybe, I wonder if he's trying to use handlebars helpers then.  We'll have to see.

Comment: Thanks guys, again... I am over thinking this! :)